# outlook start time to java calendar?

Tags: java

How to change the outlook start time to java calendar

In outlook I set start time = Tue 7/13/2010 5:00 p.m. When i parse the ics file it gives the data like this

```
 ......
 BEGIN:VEVENT
 DTSTART:20100713T113000Z
 DTEND:20100714T120000Z
 ........
 ..........
```

i have to set start time to google calendar's event add start time.How to make this time to java calendar time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.parse("20100713T113000Z"));
```

Answer (score 1):

By using Javas [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can parse a calendar from a String

Comment: To be more accurate, you can parse a `java.util.Date` from a String; but it's easy to initialize a Calendar object from that.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for clearing up, it's a Date that is returned.